# Get title of window without switching in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, window-handles

Is there any way to get window title without making any switch in selenium?

presently I'm using below code:

```
public boolean switchToWindowByTitle(String title){
    String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
    Set<String> availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    if (!availableWindows.isEmpty()) { 
         for (String windowId : availableWindows) {
              String switchedWindowTitle=driver.switchTo().window(windowId).getTitle();
              if ((switchedWindowTitle.equals(title))||(switchedWindowTitle.contains(title))){ 
                  return true; 
              } else { 
                driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow); 
              } 
          } 
     } 
     return false;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. If you want to get the window title, then it should appear over there.

Comment: ' Ok. Does driver.getWindowHandles() return all window handler in sequence in which they appear on page (hierarchy)?'

Comment: do you have multiple tabs and you want to get their title?

Comment: Don't have multiple tab. In application, we have additional functionality which closes all child window if user clicks outside of child window. Same thing happening when we are iterating over set of window handler. Due to this, we are looking some other approach to do same.

Answer (score 0):

[Page Title](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-title-of-a-webpage-using-selenium-in-python/) is the `<title>` tag and appears at the top of a browser window which is part of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) within the `<header>` section of the `<html>`.

So *Selenium* driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) needs to have the [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726121/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-doesnt-get-focus-on-the-window/51726263#51726263) on the specific *Browsing Context* to extract the *Page Title*.

Where as [Window Handle](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/handle-multiple-windows-in-selenium) is a unique identifier that holds the address of all the windows and can return the string value. All the browser will have a unique window handle. This `getWindowHandles()` function helps to retrieve the handles of all windows.

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven *WebDriver* can collect the *Window Handles* from the *Browsing Context* even without having individual [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757181/how-to-bring-the-browser-window-to-front-which-is-opened-by-selenium-web-driver/43757717#43757717) on them.

---

### Conclusion

So it is **not** possible to get the title of window/tab without switching to the specific *Window / TAB*.

Answer (score -3):

This Code will do the purpose. Call this function as follows 
swithToWindow("window Name");

```
public static Boolean switchToWindow(String title) {
    String Parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String handle : handles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(Parent_window);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP was asking for: How _not_ to switch the window.

Answer (score -3):

```
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

            String parentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

               Set<String> windows= driver.getWindowHandles();
               for(String child:windows){
                   try{
                   if(!child.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindow)){
                          driver.switchTo().window(child);
                          String windowTitle=driver.getTitle();
                          if(windowTitle.equals("book My Show")){
                              System.out.println("Window found");

                          }
                          else{
                              System.out.println("no windows found");
                          }

                   }
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       System.out.println("");
                   }
               }
               driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

}
}

Comment: This basically the same logic as what OP already had. He is asking to do this *without* switching to all windows to get the title.