# How to bring the browser window to front which is opened by selenium web driver

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver

Browser chrome will be opened by selenium and executing some operations, but its seems to be not bring to front even it focused. How can i make this chrome window bring to front?

Comment: Provide more info: 1. What are your testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Show error stacktrace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: @Dev Actually chrome window has opened and working well as i scripted.  but if i switch to any other window opened, i need this chrome window bring to front which means always this chrome window should be in front until i call driver.quit();

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Before you switch to any other window opened store the parent window handle in a String: `String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();`
2. Switch to any other window & perform your actions.
3. Finally, switch back to the parent window through the parent window handle stored in a String: `driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);`
4. Perform the rest of your operations and call `driver.quit();`

Let me know if this Answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Set this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");
```

and then add this line

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```