# Is there any way to get all tab titles of browser without switching?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can get the all the opened tab titles by switching to each tab. Like below,

**Code**:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(i));
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
```

**Output**:

```
Google
Home
```

Is there any way to get all the titles without switching? Something like below,

```
for(String tab : tabs){
  System.out.println(tab)
}
```

but the above code is returning the tab id's.

```
CDwindow-54AD3D4D73FFC6A60F79C1E56B131C2B
CDwindow-046B8E378703FEAAD1002BF3F835BAB7
```

Comment: I see this question was already asked and the answer is: No, it is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760357/get-title-of-window-without-switching-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Any possible solution using javascript?

Comment: I do not know. Otherwise I would give it you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Window Handle

[**Window Handle**](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/handle-multiple-windows-in-selenium) is a unique identifier that holds the address of all the windows. It as a pointer to a window, which can return the string value. It is assumed that each browser will have a unique window handle. This window handle function helps to retrieve the handles of all windows.

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven *WebDriver* can collect the *Window Handles* from the *Browsing Context* even without having individual [***focus***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757181/how-to-bring-the-browser-window-to-front-which-is-opened-by-selenium-web-driver/43757717#43757717) on them.

---

### Page Title

The [**Page Title**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-title-of-a-webpage-using-selenium-in-python/) is the `<title>` tag, which is a short description of a webpage and appears at the top of a browser window and is part of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) within the `<header>`.

So *Selenium* driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) needs to have the [***focus***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726121/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-doesnt-get-focus-on-the-window/51726263#51726263) on the specific *Browsing Context* to extract the *Page Title*.

---

### Conclusion

So there is **no** way to get all the tab titles of the browser without switching to specific *TABs*.

Answer (score 2):

```
With Selenium, No.
```

But

```
With Helium
```

There is a tool called [helium](https://github.com/mherrmann/selenium-python-helium), you don't need to switch to the browser tab to interact with web elements.

- **Window management** : Helium notices when popups open or close and focuses / defocuses them like a user would. You can also easily switch to a window by (parts of) its title. No more having to iterate over Selenium window handles.
- **iFrames** : Unlike Selenium, Helium lets you interact with elements inside nested iFrames, without having to first "switch to" the iFrame.

But these good things come with a limation which is binding language, Helium is basically available for Python as of now.

Comment: @NandanA : It's unfortunate that we do not have helium support for Java. Anyway good luck !