# Why does the Selenium's program always automatically jump to my desktop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, focus

I  make a automated crawler for python-selenium but it's always automatically jump to my desktop.

Is it because I recycle `swicth to window()`?

Please tell me why?

Comment: It'd be great if you can share some of your code to study and rectify.

Comment: My projcet  was very chaos,i don't  even know where  the problem is.You known.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To perform any action within the *AUT(Application Under Test)* [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) needs to [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726121/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-doesnt-get-focus-on-the-window/51726263#51726263) on the elements.

Due to the [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961842/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-tab-titles-of-browser-without-switching/69962381#69962381) on the *Browsing Context*, itjumps to the foreground of your desktop.

Comment: Thanks your,bro. Your meaing was every elements needs focus！ So，only use a little  windows。

Comment: @hychaoc yeah, selenium needs focus.