# Selenium locate element fails when Chrome in background

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

This program works fine when you're focused on the window (Chrome), but when you switch to another window like Mozilla, or another app to continue doing your work, the Selenium fails to locate the element.

It should locate the element perfectly fine whether or not I open other apps over it, switch to other windows, and login without issues - that's what I want to accomplish so I can turn it into headless when it isn't giving me this error.

I tried to use driver waits too but to no avail.

The error I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00986903+2517251]
        Ordinal0 [0x0091F8E1+2095329]
        Ordinal0 [0x00822848+1058888]
        Ordinal0 [0x0084D448+1233992]
        Ordinal0 [0x0084D63B+1234491]
        Ordinal0 [0x00877812+1406994]
        Ordinal0 [0x0086650A+1336586]
        Ordinal0 [0x00875BBF+1399743]
        Ordinal0 [0x0086639B+1336219]
        Ordinal0 [0x008427A7+1189799]
        Ordinal0 [0x00843609+1193481]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B15904+1577972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BC0B97+2279047]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A16D09+534521]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A15DB9+530601]
        Ordinal0 [0x00924FF9+2117625]
        Ordinal0 [0x009298A8+2136232]
        Ordinal0 [0x009299E2+2136546]
        Ordinal0 [0x00933541+2176321]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x770EFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B47A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B47A6E+238]
```

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time

from time import sleep

root = tk.Tk()

app_width = 300
app_height = 320

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

testbtn_txt = tk.StringVar()
testbtn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=testbtn_txt, command=lambda:open_browser_func(), font="Arial", bg="#808080", fg="white", height=1, width=10)
testbtn_txt.set("Test")
testbtn.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5)


def open_browser_func():
    global driver
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

    driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
    sleep(5)

    loginuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))
    loginuser.send_keys("Username")
    sleep(5)
    loginuser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    loginuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')))
    loginuser.send_keys("Password")
    sleep(5)
    loginuser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    return driver

root.mainloop()
```

This is really annoying as it works sometimes, and sometimes not. I am unable to make this completely automated because of the error that happens when I switch to other processes.

Comment: You need better locator.

Comment: I updated my post btw. And could you please elaborate? I am new to Python.

Comment: Please See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either one of the below locators before jumping to XPath.

1. **ID**
2. **name**
3. **classname**
4. **linkText**
5. **partialLinkText**
6. **tagName**
7. **css selector**
8. **xpath**

Also, make sure that you should not be using `absolute xpath`, rather it should be `relative xpath`.

So, Instead of these

```
loginuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))
loginuser.send_keys("Username")
sleep(5)
loginuser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

loginuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')))
loginuser.send_keys("Password")
sleep(5)
loginuser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**Use this:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
loginuser  = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
loginuser.send_keys("Username", Keys.RETURN)
loginPassword = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
loginPassword.send_keys("password here", Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to work much better now but I'll have to see if any issues arise. I have one last problem which is similar to this, and it's not working the same way.

Comment: I have this code for follow button (to click on follow), but it doesn't work properly as well. I tried to search for name like you did above but couldn't find anything to locate other than xpath. Code: followuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div')))
                followuser.click()

Comment: In that case, Please use XPath based on text `//span[text()='Follow']`,  The locator that you are using should be unique in nature. XPath has the least precedence but it is one of the powerful locators.

Comment: I just found out that the error still happens even with your new code, and using headless mode.

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) needs to ***focus*** on both:

- [*Browser Window*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757181/how-to-bring-the-browser-window-to-front-which-is-opened-by-selenium-web-driver/43757717#43757717)
- [*DOM Element*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518772/how-to-focus-object-in-selenium-web-driver/59521886#59521886)

When you bring another window like Mozilla, or another app to the foreground and continue doing your work *Selenium* looses the ***focus*** from the *Browser Context*. Hence you see the error.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium stops when browser is manually interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174242/selenium-stops-when-browser-is-manually-interrupted/51174530#51174530)
- [Way to open Selenium browser not overlapping my current browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162992/way-to-open-selenium-browser-not-overlapping-my-current-browser/52164715#52164715)
- [How to execute tests with selenium webdriver while browser is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504503/how-to-execute-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-while-browser-is-minimized/52515176#52515176)
- [Sending selenium chrome instance to the background using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730392/sending-selenium-chrome-instance-to-the-background-using-python/52741949#52741949)

Comment: Oh? So it's not gonna work fine in the background? What's the way around it?

Comment: @Cassano A lot of people would suggest _**Headless**_ but I'll suggest a seperate testbed. Checkout the references updated within the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423662/7429447)

Comment: Headless do seems work a little better in this type cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about sendkeys but for click events try executing JavaScript like this ....

```
Submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Locator path") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Submit)
```

This works in every worst case scenario including in the background process...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).